# Can I automate the 'email this link' functionality via workflow?

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2015

I would like to create a workflow/action that will run weekly and send the link for a specific view for a specific entity to all users. Do you know if and how this could be done? Cheers

Comment: Does this link need to be dynamic ? or its just the same view again and again. If so then i dont see any problem

Comment: Well, it is the same link, but I didn't want to configure a static email that would have been sent every time the workflow ran. I was thinking there was some sort of way of selecting the view from a field or setting on some entity: {name(some_entity)} and the workflow takes care of this